# Can I set the total pages and on clicking to next page load the next set of records using ajax in jq grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, asp.net-ajax

I Have a dynamic Jqgrid where I am populating the data as local. This local data is been fetched using ajax and the response that I get from the ajax call is not in correct format, so I have written a extended function which gives me a result as object containing column names, column models and column data. This was pretty awesome to handle and succeeded in doing this however when the question came to populate the data on pagination i was shoot out and hang up.

I investigated on **onPaging function** and found stuff to load the grid but that doesn't full fill my requirements.

**Case that I need to implements is as below.**

1) On pagination load the JqGrid by making an ajax call.
2) Imagine I have 25 records and I need to load and populate only 5 records at one time in the Jqgrid. However the user should be displayed with the information on the top of the jqgrid saying that **1 of 5 records**  and **1 of 5 page** is displayed. Now when the user clicks on the next page I need to make a ajax and fill the next 5 records and similarly the user informed in the top saying **5 to 10 records** and **2 of 5 page** is displayed.

below is the function that is binding my grid from  the feeds.

```
function BindFeedsToGrid(data, visibleCol, loadXmlTable, pager, errorMessage) {
        try {
            var result = ConvertXmlToJson(data, visibleCol);
            if (result) {
                $("#" + errorMessage).text("");
                $("#" + loadXmlTable).jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'jsonstring',
                    datastr: result.colData,
                    colNames: result.ColNames,
                    colModel: result.ColModel,
                    pager: $("#" + pager),
                    rowNum: 5,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 25, 50],
                    viewrecords: true,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: 'auto',
                    toppager: true,
                    recordpos: 'left',
                    recordtext: 'Display {0} of {1}',
                    pagerpos: 'right',
                    pgtext: 'Page {0} of {1}',
                    total:5,
                    //BS Page start
                    onPaging: function (pgButton) {
                        //debugger;
                        var currentPage = $("#" + loadXmlTable).getGridParam('page'); //get current  page
                        var lastPage = $("#" + loadXmlTable).getGridParam("lastpage"); //get last page 

                        var dropDownVal = $("#" + loadXmlTable).closest('.ui-jqgrid').find('.ui-pg-selbox').val();

                        if (currentPage - 1 == lastPage - 1)
                            $("#" + loadXmlTable).setGridParam({ page: lastPage }).trigger("reloadGrid"); // set the requested page to the last page value – then reload

                        var currentRecordCount = $("#" + loadXmlTable).getGridParam("reccount");  //get the record count
                        var recordsPerPage = $("#" + loadXmlTable).getGridParam("rowNum");  // get the records per page

                        var newValue = 0;  // new value
                        if (pgButton === "user") {
                            newValue = $(".ui-pg-input").val(); 
                        }
                        else {

                            if (pgButton.indexOf("next") >= 0)
                                newValue = ++currentPage;
                            else if (pgButton.indexOf("prev") >= 0)
                                newValue = --currentPage;
                            else if (pgButton.indexOf("last") >= 0)
                                newValue = $("#" + loadXmlTable).getGridParam('lastpage');
                            else if (pgButton.indexOf("first") >= 0)
                                newValue = 1;
                        }

                        page = newValue > 0 ? newValue : currentPage;
                        pageSize = dropDownVal;

                        var tempres = setNextSetOfData();
                        $("#" + loadXmlTable).jqGrid("setGridParam",{ datastr: tempres.colData ,colNames:tempres.colNames,colModel:tempres.colModel }).trigger("reloadGrid");                            
                    },
                    //BS page end

                    gridComplete: function () {
                        var recs = parseInt($("#" + loadXmlTable.id).getGridParam("records"), 10);
                        if (isNaN(recs) || recs == 0) {
                            $("#gridWrapper").hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#gridWrapper').show();
                        }
                    }
                });                
                //$("#" + loadXmlTable).jqGrid('navGrid', '#' + pager, { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false },
                //                {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, showQuery: true });

            }
            else {
                $("#" + errorMessage).text("There is no available item/items to display in this list");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            $("#" + errorMessage).text("Server did not Respond. Please check Domain/Server url in the edit part.").css({ "color": "red", "font-weight": "bold" });
        }


    }
```

**Updated 1 :** 
I am constructing the Json Object using the sample xml given below

```
    <properties xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <property>
    <name>Accessed</name>
    <value>14.01.2016 12:20:08</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Case no.</name>
    <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?name=Common.Details.Navigate&amp;module=Case&amp;subtype=2&amp;recno=200017</url>
    <value>16/00017</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Title</name>
    <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?name=Common.Details.Navigate&amp;module=Case&amp;subtype=2&amp;recno=200017</url>
    <value>San Case 16</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Type</name>
    <value>Case</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Responsible person</name>
    <value>Administrator</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Responsible unit</name>
    <value>Products</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Status</name>
    <value>In progress</value>
  </property>
</properties>
<properties xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <property>
    <name>Accessed</name>
    <value>14.01.2016 12:20:08</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Case no.</name>
    <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?name=Common.Details.Navigate&amp;module=Case&amp;subtype=2&amp;recno=200017</url>
    <value>16/00017</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Title</name>
    <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?name=Common.Details.Navigate&amp;module=Case&amp;subtype=2&amp;recno=200017</url>
    <value>San Case 16</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Type</name>
    <value>Case</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Responsible person</name>
    <value>Administrator</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Responsible unit</name>
    <value>Products</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Status</name>
    <value>In progress</value>
  </property>
</properties>
<properties xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <property>
    <name>Accessed</name>
    <value>14.01.2016 12:20:08</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Case no.</name>
    <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?name=Common.Details.Navigate&amp;module=Case&amp;subtype=2&amp;recno=200017</url>
    <value>16/00017</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Title</name>
    <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?name=Common.Details.Navigate&amp;module=Case&amp;subtype=2&amp;recno=200017</url>
    <value>San Case 16</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Type</name>
    <value>Case</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Responsible person</name>
    <value>Administrator</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Responsible unit</name>
    <value>Products</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>Status</name>
    <value>In progress</value>
  </property>
</properties>
```

**Update 2:**  Code that is converting the xml to json is as below.

```
xml2JsonInGridFormat: function xml2JsonInGridFormat(xml, visibleColoumns) {
                if (xml.length > 0) {
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
                    var result = {};
                    var colData = new Array();
                    var colNames = new Array();
                    var colModels = new Array();
                    //Build column Name         
                    var NameProperties = xml[0].getElementsByTagName("name");
                    for (var j = 0; j < NameProperties.length; j++) {
                        var colName = NameProperties[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        colNames.push(colName);
                    }
                    //Build column Model
                    var Modelproperties = xml[0].getElementsByTagName("property");
                    for (var i = 0; i < Modelproperties.length; i++) {
                        var colModel = null;                     
                        colModel = {
                            'name': Modelproperties[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,                            
                            sortable: true,
                            unformat: true,
                            shrinkToFit: false,
                            hidden: HideColumn(Modelproperties[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, visibleColoumns),
                            width: "120px"
                        }                        
                        colModels.push(colModel);                        
                    }
                    //Build Row Data                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
                        var rows = xml[i].getElementsByTagName("property");
                        var row = {}
                        for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                            var cellKey = "", cellValue = "";
                            if (rows[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0] != undefined)
                                cellKey = rows[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            if (rows[j].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0] != undefined) {
                                if (rows[j].getElementsByTagName("url").length > 0)
                                    cellValue = buildURL($(rows[j].getElementsByTagName("url")).text(), HtmlEncode($(rows[j].getElementsByTagName("value")).text()));
                                else
                                    cellValue = HtmlEncode(rows[j].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); //rows[j].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            }
                            row[cellKey] = cellValue;
                        }
                        colData.push(row);
                    }
                    result["ColNames"] = colNames;
                    result["ColModel"] = colModels;
                    result["colData"] = colData;
                    return result;
                }
            },
```

**OUTPUT:**

```html
ass="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-jqgrid-caption ui-widget-header ui-corner-top ui-helper-clearfix" style="display: none;"><a role="link" class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close ui-corner-all HeaderButton" style="right: 0px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span></a><span class="ui-jqgrid-title"></span></div><div id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager" class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-toppager" dir="ltr" style="width: 750px;"><div id="pg_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager" class="ui-pager-control" role="group"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ui-pg-table" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;height:100%;" role="row"><tbody><tr><td id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager_left" align="left"><div dir="ltr" style="text-align:left" class="ui-paging-info">Display 1 of 5</div></td><td id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager_center" align="center" style="white-space:pre;"></td><td id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager_right" align="right" style="width: 262px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout:auto;" class="ui-pg-table"><tbody><tr><td id="first_t_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-first"></span></td><td id="prev_t_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-prev"></span></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-state-disabled" style="width:4px;"><span class="ui-separator"></span></td><td dir="ltr">Page <input class="ui-pg-input" type="text" size="2" maxlength="7" value="0" role="textbox"> of <span id="sp_1_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager">1</span></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-state-disabled" style="width:4px;"><span class="ui-separator"></span></td><td id="next_t_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next"></span></td><td id="last_t_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_toppager" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-end"></span></td><td dir="ltr"><select class="ui-pg-selbox" role="listbox"><option role="option" value="5">5</option><option role="option" value="10">10</option><option role="option" value="25">25</option><option role="option" value="50">50</option></select></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv" style="width: 750px;"><div class="ui-jqgrid-hbox"><table class="ui-jqgrid-htable" style="width:750px" role="grid" aria-labelledby="gbox_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><thead><tr class="ui-jqgrid-labels" role="rowheader"><th id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Accessed" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 120px; display: none;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Accessed" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">Accessed<span class="s-ico" style=""><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></div></th><th id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Case no." role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 120px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Case no." class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">Case no.<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></div></th><th id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Title" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 120px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Title" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">Title<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></div></th><th id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Type" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 120px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Type" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">Type<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></div></th><th id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible person" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 120px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible person" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">Responsible person<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></div></th><th id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible unit" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 120px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible unit" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">Responsible unit<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></div></th><th id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Status" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 120px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Status" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">Status<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></div></th></tr></thead></table></div></div><div class="ui-jqgrid-bdiv" style="height: auto; width: 750px;"><div style="position:relative;"><div></div><table id="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData" tabindex="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="gbox_ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" style="width: 750px;"><tbody><tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row" style="height:auto"><td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:120px;display:none;"></td><td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:120px;"></td><td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:120px;"></td><td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:120px;"></td><td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:120px;"></td><td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:120px;"></td><td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:120px;"></td></tr><tr role="row" id="1" tabindex="0" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight" aria-selected="true"><td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="14.01.2016 12:20:08" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Accessed">14.01.2016 12:20:08</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="16/00017" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Case no."><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200017" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">16/00017</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="San Case 16" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Title"><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200017" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">San Case 16</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Case" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Type">Case</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Admin" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible person">Admin</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Product" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible unit">Product</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="In progress" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Status">In progress</td></tr><tr role="row" id="2" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr"><td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="14.01.2016 12:19:54" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Accessed">14.01.2016 12:19:54</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="16/00016" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Case no."><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200016" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">16/00016</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="San Case 15" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Title"><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200016" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">San Case 15</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Case" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Type">Case</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Admin" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible person">Admin</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Product" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible unit">Product</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="In progress" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Status">In progress</td></tr><tr role="row" id="3" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr"><td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="14.01.2016 12:19:41" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Accessed">14.01.2016 12:19:41</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="16/00015" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Case no."><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200015" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">16/00015</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="San Case 14" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Title"><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200015" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">San Case 14</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Case" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Type">Case</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Admin" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible person">Admin</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Product" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible unit">Product</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="In progress" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Status">In progress</td></tr><tr role="row" id="4" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr"><td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="14.01.2016 12:19:25" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Accessed">14.01.2016 12:19:25</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="16/00014" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Case no."><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200014" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">16/00014</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="San Case 13" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Title"><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200014" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">San Case 13</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Case" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Type">Case</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Admin" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible person">Admin</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Product" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible unit">Product</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="In progress" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Status">In progress</td></tr><tr role="row" id="5" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr"><td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" title="14.01.2016 12:19:07" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Accessed">14.01.2016 12:19:07</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="16/00013" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Case no."><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200013" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">16/00013</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="San Case 12" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Title"><a href="http://localhost/locator.aspxID=200013" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">San Case 12</a></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Case" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Type">Case</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Admin" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible person">Admin</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Product" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Responsible unit">Product</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="In progress" aria-describedby="ctl00_ctl26_g_a1029eec_9a07_4328_bc41_c4aed6a95157_loadXMLData_Status">In progress</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
```

Comment: How many rows of data exist in the grid which you need to display (100, 1000, 10000, 1000000)? jqGrid support `datatype: "xml"` and one can use `xmlReader` and `xmlmap` to read the original data. In case of low number of rows (about 1000 or 10000) it's more effective to load all data at once using `loadonce: true` option and to allow jqGrid make **local** paging, sorting, filtering/searching of data. You will need to write very small server and client code and the user will fill better performance of your grid. Which version and fork of jqGrid you use?

Comment: @oleg..  Number of records I have to display in the grid per page is a configurable. Most often it would be 100 records per page. And when the user moves to next page I'm planning to fetch the next set of 100 records and display in the grid.  Xml that I get is not in a proper format if I bind that to jqgrid it will not meet to my requirements.

Comment: Sorry, but I asked you about **total number** of all records in all pages. It would be helpful to include an example of XML data (with 2-3 items). In general jqGrid allows you to parse piratically every input data.

Comment: @Oleg I have updated the solution with xml sample. Hope this will help you any way

Comment: I asked you two times about the total number of rows in all pages. Why you ignore the question?

Comment: @oleg I'm sorry.  5 rows per page and total number of records are 25 and 5 pages. Hope you have found that in the question

Comment: @Oleg Hi I have updated the solution with the input and output. Hope you find it helpful. Now with this XML can i build this Jqgird?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your current question. You change the format of input data multiple times. Now you posted one more fragment of XML data without any root element. You don't described in any way the exact format of input data. It's unclear how you want to display the information in the table: which columns should have the grid and so on. The updated parts of the question have already no relation to the original question about paging the data. My answer on your original question was: reading of XML data and usage of `loadonce: true` for *local* paging without processing `onPaging`.

Comment: @oleg: you suggested me not to convert to json and bind the grid by giving the the url. Therefore I was seeking how to bind this kind of XML data to the grid. Yes, you are correct there is  no root element in the grid. but you can have one. My main intention is to populate this kind of he data in grid and then allow pagination and sorting

Comment: @oleg:  Actually I have given 3 properties node. Therefore if you consider this xml as the input you should get 3 rows with one header. But In my output code you will find more than 3 because I have added some more rows for simplicity and understanding purpose

Comment: 1) I mean that well-formatted XML have to have one root node. You posted **fragment** of XML data (no parent to multiple `<properties>`). 2) You current fragment of XML data contains multiple `properties` which have multiple `property`, which have multiple `name`, `value` and optional `url`. **You don't posted any description of the data or XSD Schema**. The structure `properties/property/name` is too deep to be displayed as grid/table in common case.

Comment: 2) Multiple `properties` items from your XML have *the same* set of name values "Accessed", "Case no.", "Title", "Type", "Responsible person", "Responsible unit", "Status". It can be that the set of values are the columns, which you need to display, the `properties` specify *the row* of the data. But I guess only because I have no idea how could look the next set of data. I suggest you the describe **exactly** the format of input data *in separate question*. You current comments and changes become to make your original question to "The NeverEnding Story".

Comment: @Oleg  yes you are correct. I will post that as another separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I would don't recommend you to implement some complex paging logic in `onPaging`. The XML input data which you use is very simple and very small (about 25 rows). Instead of that I'd recommend you to load the data by URL directly from the server and to use `loadonce: true`, which inform jqGrid read all data at once, save there in the local `data` property and to use the data for local paging, sorting and filtering.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/SanjuRao.htm) uses the following code

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "xml",
    url: "SanjuRao.xml",
    colNames: ["Name", "Value"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "name" },
        { name: "value" }
    ],
    cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, width: 200 },
    autoResizing: { compact: true },
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 25, "10000:All"],
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: true,
    toppager: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    loadonce: true,
    sortname: "name",
    forceClientSorting: true,
    xmlReader: {
        root: "properties",
        row: "property",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    searching: {
        closeAfterSearch: true,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        multipleSearch: true,
        multipleGroup: true,
        defaultSearch: "cn"
    }
})
.jqGrid("navGrid", { add: false, edit: false, del: false})
.jqGrid("filterToolbar");
```

It displays the grid like on the picture below

[image]

It loads the data from the serve (from static file in the demo), sort the data on the client side and displays the first page. You can remove `toppager: true` if you don't need the top pager. One can use the filter toolbar for quick filtering of data (added by `filterToolbar`) and search dialog for more complex filtering of the data (added by `navGrid`). I used [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) in the demo. It's the fork of jqGrid which I develop. It has some extended features like `forceClientSorting: true`.

**UPDATED:** To display `value` column as link if `url` property is defined you can use custom formatter. You need just add

```
additionalProperty: ["url"]
```

to inform free jqGrid to read additional property of input data and to use the following definition of the column `value`:

```
{
    name: "value",
    formatter: function (cellValue, options) {
        var item = options.rowData;
        if (item.url) {
            return "<a class='mylink' href='" + item.url + "'>" + cellValue + "</a>";
        } else {
            return cellValue;
        }
    }
}
```

See [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/SanjuRao1.htm), where `mylink` defined the CSS style of the link. For example

```css
.mylink {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The displayed results looks like on the next picture

[image]

Small remark. I included setting of `mylink` class and `text-decoration: underline;` CSS rule only because I used `bootstrap.css` in the demo. One don't need to do this if you don't need bootstrap (it's not required for jqGrid).

Comment: 25 is just an example. However the Accessed,Case no. Responsible person and etc etc are the column names. So each property tag has 3 fields. Name,URL,Value                                                                                              .Each property elements can have 3 child elements 
<name> element is the name of the column 
<value> element is the value of the row in <name> column. 

an extra element is URL, If there is url then that column should be an hyperlink column.

Comment: @SanjuRao: The code which I suggest works not only with 25 rows. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) which loads 40000 rows and 13 columns. It uses 20 rows in the page. It displays the loading time, sorting fime and filtering time in ms. You can see that local grid works quickly enough. To process `url` you need just use custom formatter. See [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/SanjuRao1.htm) and **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Can you have the multiple **properties**  tag that is given in the sample and then build the Jqgrid? remember even columns are repeated as many times as the rows.  Like say the column name **Case No.** is repeated multiple times for each case number if it is starting from **1 to 25**

Comment: @SanjuRao: Sorry, I don't full understand what you mean. You posted no XML Schema of your XML file and just an example. Everything is possible of cause. One should just clear know the format of input data and to write the code which corresponds the data. The `row` property of `xmlReader` can be defined as function. In the same way you can include `xmlmap` in every column definition which could be function too. The `xmlmap` will get the row item as parameter and it should return the results of reading. One can use `xmlmap: "[attributeName]"` for example to read attributes instead of elements.

Comment: thanks for helping me around. your answers and discussion has helped me sort. so marking it as helpful